# copy heroku app local

Tags: django, heroku, windows-7, development-environment

A customer of mine has a Heroku Python/Django application that they have asked me to take a look at and I am trying to understand the process of getting it running on my local Windows 7 laptop. I have been searching the net without any success. Does anyone have a suggestions or guides on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look here : [Collaborating with Others](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sharing)

They should add you as a collaborator so you can `git clone` the project files. They can do it via the heroku toolbelt installed on their computer (in command line) or via the  [Dashboard heroku](https://id.heroku.com/login)